Typescript Union type - field type override
I have following sample code that behaviour is not clear to me.
type A = {
  field: string
}

type B = {
  field: number
}

//I expect A | B is equivalent to field: A["field"] | B["field"]

type AORB = A | B

type AORBField = {
  field: A["field"] | B["field"]
}

type BaseTypes = {
  field: number | string
}

//Toggle between AORB and AORBField
type AB = AORB;
//type AB = AORBField;
//type AB = BaseTypes

const isA = (t: AB): t is A => {
  return typeof t.field === "string"
}

const isB = (t: AB): t is B => {
  return typeof t.field === "number"
}

const test = (x: AB) => {}
const testA = (x: A) => {}
const testB = (x: B) => {}
const testString = (x: string) => {}
const testNumber = (x: number) => {}

const getField = () => {
  const val = Math.random();
  return Math.random() % 2 ? val.toString(): val
}

const getDummyObject = () => {
  const val = Math.random();
  return { field: Math.random() % 2 ? val.toString(): val }
}

//Why error?
const ab: AB = {
  //field: 1 //This will pass for AORB
  //field: "string" //This will pass for AORB
  field: getField() //This will pass for AORBFields
}

//Why error?
const abc: AB = getDummyObject();


if (isA(ab)){
  const a: A = ab;
  testString(a.field)
  testNumber(a.field) //Expected err
  testA(a)
  test(ab)
}
else
{
  const b: B = ab; //This will fail for AORBField and BaseTypes, but that is expected since else statement cannot figure out main type
  testString(b.field) //Expected err
  testNumber(b.field)
  testB(b)
  test(ab)
}

There is a typescript error on ab and abc assignment that is surprising to me. I expect following types are alike AORB = AORBField = BaseTypes at least in context of what we can assign to them. Obviously only AORB would correctly infer type on "If else" statement.
I've failed to find explanation in TS docs, could someone enlighten me here?

That isn't how a union of product types works, and for the most part it isn't how you'd want them to work. You can't assign { field: string | number } to either A or B, so you can't assign that to the union of A | B either: it can't satisfy either type of the union.

That isn't how a union of object types works, and for the most part it isn't how you'd want them to work (although your particular case may be an exception). The return type of your getDummyObject is { field: string | number } and you can't assign that to either A or B, so you can't assign that to the union A | B either: it can't satisfy either type of the union. The two types don't "mix" the way you seem to want them to.
type A = {
  field: number
}

type B = {
  field: string
}

type AB = A | B

// return type of getDummyObject
type Neither = {
  field: string | number
}

type Test1 = Neither extends A ? A : never   // never
type Test2 = Neither extends B ? B : never   // never
type Test3 = Neither extends AB ? AB : never // never

Which makes sense if you think about it, how could something that's neither an A nor a B be assigned to something that's either an A or a B?
If you change the code in getDummyObject to be
const getDummyObject = () => {
  const val = Math.random();
  return Math.random() % 2 ? 
    { field: val.toString() } : 
    { field: val };
}

then it works just fine
const foo: AB = getDummyObject(); // no error

Playground

Note that discriminated unions do kind of work this way, at least for "small" unions, due to the "smarter" union type checking support added in TS3.5

@jcalz that's a good call out, but I'm curious as to how it would relate to the OP's example? If we add a discriminant to the A and B types OP would still have to move the ternary outside the object in getDummyObject in order to have the relevant value of the discriminant.

If, instead of string and number, you've got literals like "a" and 2, then suddenly it all works the way they expect.

@jcalz right, I get that from the boolean example in the docs you linked, and I'll edit my answer to mention it, I just am a little afraid that particular nuance might be confusing to folks who are struggling with the basic concept of why the types in the union don't "mix" at the property level.

I don't know that you need to add that, but it's one of those things that fools people into thinking unions do work that way.

Good deal, I'll just leave it in the comments then, anybody that curious can scroll down :)
